# unable to connect to the remote server - GoDaddy upload

Tags: ftp, upload

I Received (randomly) this error while uploading to GoDaddy's FTP server some bitmap:
"unable to connect to the remote server"

This is my code:

```
  public static string UploadFileToFTP(byte[] image, string targetpath, string source, string imgName)
    {

        string ftpurl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Ftp_Images_Domain"];
        string ftpusername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Ftp_Images_Usr"];
        string ftppassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Ftp_Images_Pwd"];

        try
        {
            SetMethodRequiresCWD();

            string ftpfullpath = ftpurl + targetpath + source;

            FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
            ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);
            ftp.KeepAlive = false;
            ftp.UseBinary = true;
            ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            using (Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream())
            {

                ftpstream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
                //image.InputStream.CopyTo(ftpstream);
            }
            return "Success";
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            String status = ((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;
            logger.Error(e);
            return status;
        }
    }
```

This happened all of the sudden for no known reason. And of course, no good answer from the hosting company as well :)
For those who bump into this, what I did was:

1. Created another fresh FTP account
2. Gave read/write permissions to the FTP account

This solved the problem.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

1. Create another fresh FTP account
2. Give read/write permissions to the FTP account

This could solve the problem.